# pre-population variables from encrypted buttons

Tags: php

My BuyNow buttons are encrypted with the customer personal information. I would like to pre-populate this information on the PP website so that the customer does not have to re-enter it. This is important especially if the buyer wants to use his/her own credit card. Apparently this does not seem to work as the information does not show up once in the PayPal site. Does PP support pre-population using encrypted buttons or do I have to duplicate the passing of customer data via hidden fields?

Comment: i don't think paypal supports such a feature. normally you should not send credit card information in url's even if it's encrypted. anything can be decrypted eventually.